# TikZ Angles Library - Angle correct size but offset by some degrees

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf, tikz-angles

I'm trying to draw complex argument loci on an argand diagram. Therefore, I need to draw half-lines and label their angles. So far, I have this, and the problem is the angle is off by some amount. Any fixes?

p.s. If anyone could find me a way such that I only have to specify the coordinate S and angle `\angle`, for it to draw automatically, that would be appreciated(What the angle command draws is made red for debugging purposes)

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    % Bla Bla Bla...
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
    \usetikzlibrary{angles}
    \usetikzlibrary{quotes}
    \usetikzlibrary{babel}
    % Some content Etc....
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,name=#1},
        extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
        extended line/.default=50cm, scale=2]
            % ----- Zoom and clip ----- %
            \clip (-4,-2) rectangle (2,2);
            \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-19,-19) grid (19,19);
                        
            % ----- Coordinates ----- %
            \def\angle{pi/4 r};
                        
            \coordinate (O) at (0, 0); % Origin
            \coordinate (S) at (-3, 1); % Start of half-line
            \coordinate (B) at (10, 0); % Base Line
            \coordinate (L) at ({\angle}: 13); % The half-line
                        
            % ----- Main ----- %
            \draw (B)--(S)--(L) pic [draw=green!50!black, fill=green!20, angle radius=2cm, "$\frac{\pi}{4}$"] {angle = B--S--L};
                        
            \draw[very thick] (S) -- +(L);
            \draw[very thick, dashed] (S) -- +(B);
                        
            % ----- Axes ----- %
            \draw[->,ultra thick] (-19,0)--(19,0) node[right]{$x$};
            \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-19)--(0,19) node[above]{$y$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

[image: My dilemma: tilted angle]

Comment: There is a difference between `\draw[very thick] (S) -- (L);` and `\draw[very thick] (S) -- +(L);`, which explains the discrepancy between the thick and thin lines.

Comment: @abcdefg It's because I wanted it relative to the start of the halfline. Otherwise it would point to the absolute point that is defined by L.

Comment: Well, but you do draw the angle for the absolute point, which is why there is a mismatch. How would the angle know that you mean something else?

Comment: Yes and that's why I tried to make intermediate coordinates which are the results of adding the start coordinate and the half-line, but it still doesn't work. If you have the time to write up an answer or explain this discrepancy and why it makes my angles offset I would really appreciate it.

Comment: "that's why I tried to make intermediate coordinates which are the results of adding the start coordinate and the half-line": it is hard for me to see this in your code. You can use `\path (S) +(L) coordinate (L');` and `\path (S) +(B) coordinate (B');` to define `L'` and `S'` and use those in the angle.

Comment: I removed it from the code long ago; it was a previous attempt. But thanks for the help. I'll try it pronto.

Comment: @abcdefg Thing is, it works but then the dashed base line that I wanted is now covered by a thick solid line so you can't see it. Any fixes?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it is not clear what you after. Considering @abcdefg comments, Your MWE can be rewritten as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
                %calc,
                %intersections,
                quotes,
                babel}  % for language issues

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
%dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,name=#1},
extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
extended line/.default=50cm, scale=2,
myangle/.style = {draw=#1!50!black, fill=#1!20, 
                  angle eccentricity=0.8,  angle radius=12m}
                        ]
% ----- Zoom and clip ----- %
\clip (-4,-2) rectangle (2,2);
\draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-19,-19) grid (19,19);

% ----- Coordinates ----- %
\def\angle{pi/4 r};
%\coordinate (O) at ( 0, 0); % Origin
\coordinate (S) at (-3, 1); % Start of half-line
\path   (S) -- ++ (0:10)        coordinate (B)  % Base Line
        (S) -- ++ (\angle:13)   coordinate (L); % The half-line

% ----- Main ----- %
\pic [myangle=orange, "$\frac{\pi}{4}$"] {angle = B--S--L}; % <--- instead of "orange" select your color as you wish

\draw[very thick,cap=round] (S) -- (L);
\draw[very thick, dashed]   (S) -- (B);

% ----- Axes ----- %
\draw[->,ultra thick] (-19,0)--(19,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-19)--(0,19) node[above]{$y$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In above MWE are commented all libraries and style definitions from your MWE which are not used here. Also for focusing to diagram, used is `standalone` document class, that shows is only image (and not whole page).

Small differences are also in writing angle label. For it is defined new style (`\myangle`) for shorter code. Draw is as `\pic`, so no line used in your approach are not visible anymore.

Is this what you looking for?

[image]

Comment: I was looking for the dashed line to be parallel to the x-axis because that's where all my angles will be measured from. I wanted the angle (in this case at least) to be pi/4 radians.

Comment: @HarithShah, you should be more clear in your question and have in your MWE correct positioned coordinates. I will correct this asap.

Comment: Say I wanted the color to be customisable per drawing; how would I externalise it as a variable? I managed it before when the angle style wasn't in the optional arguments, but how would it work here? i.e. I would define \anglecolor to be orange so that \anglecolor!30 would result in orange!30 etc.